Types of Hydrogenation in Reduction
There are different types of hydrogenations in organic chemistry. I know how Lindlar’s Catalyst and Transfer Hydrogenation are different from the rest of the methods.
But I want to know the difference between $H_2/Raney-Ni$, $H_2/Pd-C$ and $H_2$ with Wilkinson’s Catalyst. Do they perform the reduction differently?
Also please provide the functional groups which each of them is unable to reduce.
The above question is NOT similar to any of the other questions asked on this website.

Can  you provide your thoughts on this matter so we can correct you or suggest some details?

'The above question is NOT similar to any of the other questions asked on this website."? Did you checked them all perchance? I suggest to NEVER say that. I'm very much tempted to prove you wrong. The again it's simply too broad.
